# Yaml Build Scripts - Run Tasks by git branch

Tags: git, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a build script that I want to run some build steps for code on `master`, `features/*` and `releases/*`, and then some publishing features **only** on `master` and `releases/*` branches.

I can't seem to locate any documentation for sectioning out the build script by branches.  Here's a rough overview of my build script (just the tasks, leaving off params for brevity)

```
trigger:
- master
- releases/*
- features/*

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

name: $(Major).$(Minor).$(rev:r)
variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  Major: 1
  Minor: 1

steps:

- task: NuGetCommand@2

- task: VSBuild@1

- task: VSTest@2

## I would like everything below this line to only be run on releases/* or master

- task: WhiteSource Bolt@20

- task: NuGetCommand@2

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
```

The second half would need to run conditionally, and only if the top half is successful.  I am open to splitting these out into two scripts in it makes it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `- ${{if...}}:` script block in your pipeline. See below example:

```
 steps:
 - powershell: echo "task 0"    
   displayName: task 0

 - ${{ if or(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'],'refs/heads/master'), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'],'refs/heads/release/')) }}:  

   - powershell: echo "task 1"
     displayName: task 1

   - powershell: echo "task 2"
     displayName: task 2
```

Note: Yaml pipeline probably will hightlight above the `- ${{if...}}` script block with red wavy lines. But it will disappear after you save the pipeline. And the **indentation** is very important.

In above example, if the `- ${{if...}}` script block is evaluated to true, then task 1 and task 2 will be executed. See below screenshot from above yaml example:
[image]

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#parameters-to-select-a-template-at-runtime) for more information about `- ${{if...}}` script block. And [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops) for the Expressions you can use in azure yaml pipeline.

Another workaround is to use [conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) as Shayki mentioned. But i use expression  `startsWith` to check the branch `- releases/*`. See below example:

```
steps:
 - powershell: echo "task 0"    
   displayName: task 0

 - powershell: echo "task 1"
   condition: or(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'],'refs/heads/master'), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'],'refs/heads/releases/'))
   displayName: task 1

 - powershell: echo "task 2"
   condition: or(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'],'refs/heads/master'), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'],'refs/heads/releases/'))
   displayName: task 2
```

Comment: Thanks Levi, we found that the wild card is not observed for the IN, so we had to do the `startsWith` as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [custom condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#examples) with that check the branch name:

```
and(succeeded(), in(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master', 'refs/heads/releases/*'))
```

In YAML you add in the step:

```
condition: and(succeeded(), in(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master', 'refs/heads/releases/*'))
```

Comment: The wild card does not work with the release branches.